# Race Condition when working with DLL and WideString

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have faced following issue:
When calling the DLL function in parallel from multiple threads I get the "EAggregateException: One or more errors occurred".

The minimal DLL example is:

```
library MyDLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure MyUpper(const ASource: WideString; out AResult: WideString); stdcall;
begin
  AResult := String(ASource).ToUpper;
end;

exports
  MyUpper;

end.
```

The application which uses it:

```
program MyEXE;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Threading;

procedure MyUpper(const AText: WideString; out AResult: WideString); stdcall; external 'MyDLL.dll';

procedure Test;
var
  LLoop: TParallel.TLoopResult;
  LSync: IReadWriteSync;
begin
  LSync := TSimpleRWSync.Create;
  LLoop := TParallel.&For(1, 100000,
    procedure (AIndex: Integer)
    var
      LResult: WideString;
    begin
      MyUpper(AIndex.ToString, LResult);
    end);

  Writeln('Completed: ', LLoop.Completed);
end;

begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

If in EXE I write following:

```
AResult := ASource;
```

Then the execution succeeds. But once I use any implicit/explicit string conversion it fails. How that could be? Each thread calls this method as an usual method with it's local stack and there is no shared variables (at least visible).

I don't use any shared memory manager as I am going to use the DLL from different programming languages.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to set `IsMultiThread` to true in your dll?. Might be needed if there is no shared memory manager.

Comment: Jesus Christ! Thank you so much, @LURD!!! You saved my 3 hours of investigation!

Answer (score 2):

If the DLL is supposed to be used in the multithreaded environment then in initialization section of the library put the following line of the code:

```
IsMultiThread := True;
```